# Python or C/C++ GTK togglebutton highlight disable

Tags: python, c++, gtk

I have a set of GTK toggle buttons, that highlight on focus.  I would like to disable that highlight, but can't find any documentation on it.

I've tried in both C and Python, but cant find the right call to do so.
The borders and padding are set to 0, but what I end up with is a 5 pixel or so white box around the buttons, I think it's drawn on focus.  When I set the buttons insensitive they no longer work, but they do not inherit the highlight.

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide your code, indicating what you have tried.

Comment: And which version of GTK+?

Comment: Depending on the gtk version, you should be able to change that behaviour using CSS.